# How to dynamically fill/expand a 2d Array using a callback function in Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I want to create a dynamic function that can simplify work with array-transforming callbacks in order to fill and expand 2d Array.

## Outlining the challenge

I would like to create a function like this

```js
finalFunction({ array, header, ...args }, callbackFunctionToTransformArray)
```

> **Restrictions**
>
> - The given array is always a 2d array
> - The header is supplied as a string to be passed onto the callbackFunction
> - The callback function always has to return a "changes" Object containing the headers as Keys. The values for each key contain an array of the values to be inserted

which can pass all three scenarios given the following set input parameters (part of an input object):

```js
{
 array = [
  ["#","FirstName","LastName"]
  ["1","tim","foo"],
  ["2","kim","bar"]
],
header: "FirstName",
...args
}
```

> **Important**
>
> The challenges is not in the creation of the callback functions, but rather in the creation of the "finalFunction".

### Scenario 1: Transforming existing Array without expansion

```js
// return for the second row of the array
callback1 => {
  changes: {
    FirstName: ["Tim"]
  }
};
// return for the third row of the array
callback1 => {
  changes: {
    FirstName: ["Kim"]
  }
};

finalFunction({ array, header, ...args }, callback1)
```

should return

```js
{
  array: [
  ["#","FirstName","LastName"]
  ["1","Tim","foo"],
  ["2","Kim","bar"]
  ],
  header: "FirstName",
  ...args
}
```

### Scenario 2: Transforming existing Array with horizontal expansion

```js
// return given for the second row
callback2 => {
  changes: {
    FullName: ["Tim Foo"]
  }
};
// return given for the third row
callback2 => {
  changes: {
    FullName: ["Kim Bar"]
  }
};

finalFunction({ array, header, ...args }, callback2)
```

should return

```js
{
  array: [
  ["#","FirstName","LastName","FullName"]
  ["1","Tim","foo","Tim Foo"],
  ["2","Kim","bar","Kim Bar"]
  ],
  header: "FirstName",
  ...args
}
```

### Scenario 3: Transforming existing Array with vertical and horizontal expansion

```js
// return given for the second row
callback3 => {
  changes: {
    "Email": ["tim.foo@stackoverflow.com","timmy@gmail.com"],
    "MailType": ["Work","Personal"]
  }
};
// return given for the third row
callback3 => {
  changes: {
    "Email": ["kim.bar@stackoverflow.com","kimmy@aol.com"],
    "MailType": ["Work","Personal"]
  }
};

finalFunction({ array, header, ...args }, callback3)
```

should return

```js
{
  array: [
  ["#","FirstName","LastName","Email","MailType"]
  ["1","Tim","foo","tim.foo@stackoverflow.com","Work"],
  ["1","Tim","foo","timmy@gmail.com","Personal"],
  ["2","Kim","bar","kim.bar@stackoverflow.com","Work"],
  ["2","Kim","bar","kimmy@aol.com","Personal"]
  ],
  header: "FirstName",
  ...args
}
```

## Current progress

The wonderful @Scott Sauyet has helped me create a merging function between a 2d array and a changes object:

```js
const addInputToArray = ({ array, changes, ...rest}) => ({
  array: Object .entries (changes) .reduce ((a, [k, vs], _, __, index = array [0] .indexOf (k)) =>
    vs.reduce(
      (a, v, i) =>
        (i + 1) in a
          ? update ((i + 1), update (index, v, a [i + 1] ), a)
          : concat (a, [update (index, v, map (always (''), array [0]) )] ),
      a),
    array
  ),
  ...rest
})
```

This works great for scenario #1. However, I can't seem to get this solution to autocreate headers if they are not part of the original array.

I have however made progress on the Vertical expansion described in scenario 3.

```js
const expandVertically = ({ array, header, index = array[0].indexOf(header), ...args }, callback) => ({
      array: array.reduce((a, v, i) => {
        if (i === 0) {
          a.push(v);
        } else {
          const arrayBlock = R.repeat(v, callback(v[index]).length);
          arrayBlock.unshift(array[0]);
          const result = addInputToArray({
            changes: callback(v[index]).changes,
            array: arrayBlock
          }).array;
          result.shift();
          result.map(x => a.push(x));
        }
        return a;
      }, []),
      header,
      ...args
    })
```

In my mind, the newly created logic would have to.

1. Call the callback Function in order to retrieve the entries that could be missing for the first Header row
2. Add missing keys of "changes" object to the header row
3. Reduce over the array skipping the first row
4. Always assume an arrayblock (as it's fine if an arrayblock only has the length one, which would cover scenarios #1 and #2)
5. Assure that the arrayblock length doesn't need "length" parameter to be supplied by the callback, but rather be captured from the arraylength of values supplied for each key in the "changes" obj

## Current Challenges

1. The current solution of vertical expansion requires the callback to provide a "length" parameter in it's result in order to get the correct number of repetitions for each source row.
2. The current function to merge the "changes" with the sourceArray does not autocreate new Headers if they couldn't be found in the first row of the source array.

I feel that this is doable and it would provide great benefits to the current project I am working on, as it applies a standardized interface for all array-fillings/expansions.

However I feel stuck, particularly on how to cover all 3 scenarios in a single function.

Any ideas or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My understanding might be wrong, but it looks to me like you're expecting too much guesswork from a programming language.  With `{..., changes: {FirstName: 'Tim'}, ...}` would you expect to get `...['#2', 'Bim', 'bar'], ...`?  Why not, it just repeated the obvious transformation of the first letter: `char * 2 - 148`?  That converts `'t'` to `'T'`, so the equivalent `'k'` to `'B'` should be fine, right?  Or why not guess that the second transformation is just `name => name + 'Foo'`?  Trying to guess what you want would be *ad hoc* and too frequently wrong.  You would have to pass functions.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your insights. I hope you misunderstood me, as the challenge for me is not creating the correct Callback functions. My Challenge is to get to the "finalFunction" syntax. I have expanded and rephrased my challenges and current understanding within the question. I would greatly appreciate it if you could see if I'm making more sense now and already thank you for helping my clarify my thinking.

Comment: Ok, then I did misunderstand.  In fact,you're trying to create something like the input to [your previous question] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58052108), right?  But I do wonder why you would go through that intermediate format at this point, rather than just applying the callback functions directly to the data.

Comment: Very similar yes, just even more dynamic. The main reason I want to do it this way is because I have many of these Array Callbacks, each of which reach out to particular services (like a Gender identification API) and others. While the input for each is just a single value (Such as a specific First Name), Some of them return multiple results per input (either in multiple rows or in multiple columns), which I want to capture. Due to the vast number of services, I would like to have a unified interface handling all these types of transformations. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think I get it now, but only after solving an [only vaguely related problem](https://runkit.com/crosseye/so58362118a)!  :-)

Comment: Are you in control of the format returned by, for example, `callback3`?  I would find it much easier to work with something like `{changes: [{Email: 'tim.foo@stackoverflow.com', MailType: 'Work'}, {Email: 'timmy@gmail.com', MailType: 'Personal'}]}`.

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that you will always get matches, that if you have two emails, you will have exactly two MailTypes, etc?

Comment: Great, and thanks for the link. I have never heard of runkit before - looks like the Notebook of a functional programming wizard :-)

Comment: Yes Scott, this can be guaranteed. What could happen however is that the Callback doesn't return anything at all for a given row, but I could deal with that by passing an empty string back into the changes Obj.

Comment: Sorry I somehow missed your question regarding the object structure. In theory, I could change the structure of the changes object, but that would require rework on a lot of the existing transformation callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one attempt.  I may still be missing something here, because I entirely ignore your `header` parameter.  Is it somehow necessary, or has that functionality now been captured by the keys in the `change` objects generated by your callback functions?

```js
// Helper function
const transposeObj = (obj, len = Object .values (obj) [0] .length) => 
  [... Array (len)] .map (
    (_, i) => Object .entries (obj) .reduce (
      (a, [k, v]) => ({... a , [k]: v[i] }),
      {}
    )
  )

// Main function
const finalFunction = (
  {array: [headers, ...rows], ...rest}, 
  callback,
  changes = rows.map(r => transposeObj(callback(r).changes)),
  allHeaders = [
    ...headers, 
    ...changes 
      .flatMap (t => t .flatMap (Object.keys) )
      .filter (k => !headers .includes (k))
      .filter ((x, i, a) => a .indexOf (x) == i)
  ],
) => ({
  array: [
    allHeaders,
    ...rows .flatMap (
      (row, i) => changes [i] .map (
        change => Object .entries (change) .reduce (
          (r, [k, v]) => [
            ...r.slice(0, allHeaders .indexOf (k)), 
            v, 
            ...r.slice(allHeaders .indexOf (k) + 1)
          ],
          row.slice(0)
        )
      )
    )
  ], 
  ...rest
})


const data = {array: [["#", "FirstName", "LastName"], ["1", "tim", "foo"], ["2", "kim", "bar"]], more: 'stuff', goes: 'here'}

// Faked out to attmep
const callback1 = (row) => ({changes: {FirstName: [row[1][0].toUpperCase() + row[1].slice(1)]}})
const callback2 = (row) => ({changes: {FullName: [`${row[1]} ${row[2]}`]}})
const callback3 = (row) => ({changes: {Email: [`${row[1]}.${row[2]}@stackoverflow.com`,`${row[1]}my@gmail.com`],MailType: ["Work","Personal"]}}) 

console .log (finalFunction (data, callback1))
console .log (finalFunction (data, callback2))
console .log (finalFunction (data, callback3))
```

This uses the helper function `transposeObj`, which converts the `changes` lists into something I find more useful.  It turns this:

```js
{
  Email: ["tim.foo@stackoverflow.com", "timmy@gmail.com"],
  MailType: ["Work", "Personal"]
}
```

into this:

```js
[
  {Email: "tim.foo@stackoverflow.com", MailType: "Work"}, 
  {Email: "timmy@gmail.com",           MailType: "Personal"}
]
```

The main function accepts your callback and a data object with an `array` parameter, from which it extracts `headers` and `rows` arrays (as well as keeping track of the remaining properties in `rest`.)  It derives the `changes` by calling the `transposeObj` helper against the `changes` property result of calling the callback against each row.  Using that data it finds the new headers by getting all the keys in the `changes` objects, and removing all that are already in the array then reducing to a set of unique values.  Then it appends these new ones to the existing headers to yield `allHeaders`.

In the body of the function, we return a new object using `...rest` for the other parameters, and update `array` by starting with this new list of headers then flat-mapping `rows` with a function that takes each of those transposed object and adding all of its properties to a copy of the current row, matching indices with the the `allHeaders` to put them in the right place.

Note that if the keys of the transposed change object already exists, this technique will simply update the corresponding index in the output.

We test above with three dummy callback functions meant to just barely cover your examples.  They are not supposed to look anything like your production code.

We run each of them separately against your input, generating three separate result objects.  Note that this does not modify your input data.  If you want to apply them sequentially, you could do something like:

```js
const data1 = finalFunction (data, callback1)
console.log (data1, '-----------------------------------')
const data2 = finalFunction (data1, callback2)
console.log (data2, '-----------------------------------')
const data3 = finalFunction (data2, callback3)
console.log (data3, '-----------------------------------')
```

to get a result something like:

```
{
    array: [
        ["#", "FirstName", "LastName"],
        ["1", "Tim", "foo"],
        ["2", "Kim", "bar"]
    ],
    more: "stuff",
    goes: "here"
}
-----------------------------------
{
    array: [
        ["#", "FirstName", "LastName", "FullName"],
        ["1", "Tim","foo", "Tim foo"],
        ["2", "Kim", "bar", "Kim bar"]
    ],
    more: "stuff",
    goes: "here"
}
-----------------------------------
{
    array: [
        ["#", "FirstName", "LastName", "FullName", "Email", "MailType"],
        ["1", "Tim", "foo", "Tim foo", "Tim.foo@stackoverflow.com", "Work"],
        ["1", "Tim", "foo", "Tim foo", "Timmy@gmail.com", "Personal"],
        ["2", "Kim", "bar", "Kim bar", "Kim.bar@stackoverflow.com", "Work"],
        ["2", "Kim", "bar", "Kim bar", "Kimmy@gmail.com", "Personal"]
    ],
    more: "stuff",
    goes: "here"
}
-----------------------------------
```

Or, of course, you could just start `let data = ...` and then do `data = finalFunction(data, nextCallback)` in some sort of loop.

This function depends heavily on `flatMap`, which isn't available in all environments.  The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) suggests alternatives if you need them.  If you're still using Ramda, the [`chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) function will serve.

---

### Update

Your response chose to use Ramda instead of this raw ES6 version.  I think that if you are going to use Ramda, you can probably simplify quite a bit with a heavier dose of Ramda functions.  I'm guessing more can be done, but I think this is cleaner:

```js
// Helper function
const transposeObj = (obj) =>
  map (
    (i) => reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v[i] }), {}, toPairs(obj)),
    range (0, length (values (obj) [0]) )
  )

// Main function
const finalFunction = (
  { array: [headers, ...rows], ...rest },
  callback,
  changes = map (pipe (callback, prop('changes'), transposeObj), rows),
  allHeaders = uniq (concat (headers, chain (chain (keys), changes)))
) => ({
  array: concat([allHeaders], chain(
    (row) => map (
      pipe (
        toPairs,
        reduce((r, [k, v]) => assocPath([indexOf(k, allHeaders)], v, r), row)
      ),
      changes[indexOf(row, rows)]
    ),
    rows
  )),
  ...rest
})

const data = {array: [["#", "FirstName", "LastName"], ["1", "tim", "foo"], ["2", "kim", "bar"]], more: 'stuff', goes: 'here'}

// Faked out to attmep
const callback1 = (row) => ({changes: {FirstName: [row[1][0].toUpperCase() + row[1].slice(1)]}})
const callback2 = (row) => ({changes: {FullName: [`${row[1]} ${row[2]}`]}})
const callback3 = (row) => ({changes: {Email: [`${row[1]}.${row[2]}@stackoverflow.com`,`${row[1]}my@gmail.com`],MailType: ["Work","Personal"]}}) 

console .log (finalFunction (data, callback1))
console .log (finalFunction (data, callback2))
console .log (finalFunction (data, callback3))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {map, reduce, toPairs, range, length, values, pipe, prop, uniq, concat, chain, keys, assocPath, indexOf} = R </script>
```

Comment: Scott, you amaze me. Thanks a ton already! Don't know how you come up with this stuff. I tested it and it works very well. Regarding your question however, the `header`parameter would still be needed, as the callbacks typically receive not just the row itself, but only a specific cell of each row (just the firstname for example). As the column, in which this value is to be found is determined by the input array, I currently supply headers so the index is clear. **Note: The supplied header is of course always part of the input array**

Comment: I checked your function again and ran into browser compatibility issues. Thanks for the "chain" tip though, as I was able to get it to work with Ramda functions.

Comment: Babel would probably also help to make this work in all relatively recent browsers.  I originally wrote this with a mix of Ramda and ES6+, because that's how I think these days, but then realized that only a little work would remove the Ramda dependencies and lose little elegance in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the great input from Scott, I wanted to share a version of this functionality which doesn't utilize flatMap, but Ramda functions instead (thereby allowing more environment support.

```js
const R = require('ramda')

// Helper function
const transposeObj = (obj, len = Object.values(obj)[0].length) =>
  [...Array(len)].map((_, i) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [k, v]) => ({ ...a, [k]: v[i] }), {}));

// Main function
const finalFunction = (
  { array: [headers, ...rows], ...rest },
  callback,
  changes = rows.map(r => transposeObj(callback(r).changes)),
  allHeaders = R.flatten([
    ...headers,
    R.chain(t => R.chain(Object.keys, t), [...changes])
      .filter(k => !headers.includes(k))
      .filter((x, i, a) => a.indexOf(x) == i)
  ])
) => {
  const resultRows = R.chain(
    (row, i = R.indexOf(row, [...rows])) =>
      changes[i].map(change =>
        Object.entries(change).reduce(
          (r, [k, v]) => [...r.slice(0, allHeaders.indexOf(k)), v, ...r.slice(allHeaders.indexOf(k) + 1)],
          row.slice(0)
        )
      ),
    [...rows]
  );
  return {
    array: [allHeaders, ...resultRows],
    ...rest
  };
};
```

Comment: I updated my answer to offer what I think of as a simplification, if you're going to choose Ramda.  (I added a few other simplifications as I saw them, but this is mostly just a matter of using Ramda functions.)

Comment: One other point about this one: if you are going to have multiple statements in the body (`const resultRows = ...` and `return {...}`), then there is little reason to put `changes` and `allHeaders` as parameters.  It's a bit cleaner to keep them in the body.  The only reason I did it in my versions was because it allowed me a single-statement body.

Comment: Thanks for your further insights @scott. At the moment I'm struggling with making the function work with a promise callback as such: ````const callback4 = async row => {
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({ changes: { FullName: [`${row[1]} ${row[2]}`] } }), 1000);
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)
  return result;
};```` at the moment I always receive the following error: ````Cannot convert undefined or null to object````. Do you have any insights on how to resolve the promise correctly?

Comment: Briefly, you could change my first answer by moving the initialization of `changes` and `allHeaders` into the function body (adding `{` - `}` and a `return` statement), declaring `finalFunction` to be `async` (and therefore calling it as `finalFunction(data, callback1).then(...<something here>...)`) and changing `changes` to something like `const changes = await Promise.all(rows.map(callback)) .then(rows => rows.map(r => transposeObj(r.changes)))`. But if you want to pursue this further, I'd recommend opening a new question.  We've pushed the limits of a single question here already.

Comment: @Scott thanks for your feedback. I agree. I've solved parts of promisifying the function, but have trouble with piping callbacks which I outlined in a new quesion: [How to use Ramda Pipe function with a mix of promises and static callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58504438/how-to-use-ramda-pipe-function-with-a-mix-of-promises-and-static-callbacks)